# Why do we study symplectic geometry?

Tags: soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, ho.history-overview, sg.symplectic-geometry, motivation

What is the motivation behind studying smooth manifolds with a non-degenerate closed two-form?

The subject certainly originated from physics, but is there a deeper reason for why it is still an active subject of research in mathematics? What lead mathematicians to put so much effort to understand these objects?

Comment: There are applications to physics (Hamiltonian systems, if I'm not mistaken); you can read Arnold's book (e.g., Arnold, Gussein-Zade, Varchenko). Besides, it can be regarded as a less rigid counterpart of complex algebraic geometry.

Comment: Physics is probably why people first looked at symplectic manifolds (namely cotangent bundles), but *why* we continue to study them is deeper.  Somewhat, it is just to see the consequences of a simple condition (e.g., there are actual topological consequences to having a symplectic form on a manifold), somewhat it is because that condition appears in surprising places (e.g., co-adjoint orbits carry a symplectic structure), somewhat it is because there are continuing applications to physics (e.g., understanding quantization of classical systems), but there is more out there.

Comment: It comes from mechanics. In classical mechanics there is a symplectic 2-form. Read Classical mechanics by Arnold.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented. A question for those who closed the question: What is the difference between my question and [this](http://mathoverflow.net/q/204588) well-received question? Isn't that the same question but for a different topic (GIT)?

Comment: Symplectic geometry can be seen as a generalization of complex geometry. To each symplectic structure one finds a (unique up to homotopy) compatible almost-complex structure, which in general is not integrable. So sympl. manifolds are much more flexible than complex manifolds. For example, a 4-manifold is symplectic if and only if it is a Lefschetz pencil. In particular, every fin. pres. group is the fundamental group of a symplectic 4-manifold. By contrast, there are strong restrictions for a group to be the fundamental group of a Kähler manifold. Also, sympl. mfd. occur in mirror symmetry.

Comment: One motivation is just differential geometry: to each smooth manifold we can canonically associate a symplectic manifold, its cotangent bundle. So symplectic invariants (of the cotangent bundle) yield differential invariants (of the original manifolds).

Comment: Questions about applications are very important, and, by the way, they inspire research. It is not good to close them.